# Set row classes in read.table

Tags: r, read.table

**ENV**:
R version 3.3.1
MAC OS X 10.9.4

I have data in file like:

```
V1 | V2 | V3 
------ | ------ | ------
1   | 2 | 3
0.5 | 0.3 | 0.2
```

But when I use read.table to import the data and print it to the screen, it looks like:

```
V1 | V2 | V3 
------ | ------ | ------
1.000000   | 2.000000 | 3.0000
0.500000 | 0.300000 | 0.20000
```

Values in the first row changes from integer to float.

**Expected**:

```
V1 | V2 | V3 
------ | ------ | ------
1   | 2 | 3
0.500000 | 0.300000 | 0.20000
```

There is `colClasses` in read.table but there is no rowClasses to specific data type of rows.

Is it possible to specific rows data using read.table? I did not find any solution yet. Thanks. Any references or alternative ways would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible. `read.table` results in a `data.frame` which is (usually) a list with vectors of equal length. Each element of a vector must be of the same type as every other element. In you case, the first row elements must be converted to numeric in order to correspond with elements in subsequent rows.

Comment: read.table, then transpose using `t()`, then we can set column classes.

Comment: Does t() take a long running time? markdown tables in stackoverflow seems not work. @zx8754

Comment: `t()` transposes the data.frame.

Comment: Does t() take a long running time for big data?

Comment: Depends on the size of data.frame. Regarding markdown: read about [R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: If you're very concerned about efficiency, maybe consider `data.table::setDF(data.table::transpose(x))` instead, which will return a DF (while `t()` will give a matrix that you'll have to convert back to a DF). I doubt it will make a practical difference though.

Comment: Comments from Imo, zx8754, Frank together could be perfect answer for my current question. Thanks.